# Selecting lists from a list of list

Tags: python, list

So I have a problem with my code and can't find where I got it wrong 
I have the following `list` :

```
D = [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]]
```

Which is composed of two `list`s

```
A = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 1]]
B = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]
```

I want to complete an empty `list` P=[] like this :

```
P = [D[0][0],D[1][0],D[0][1],D[1][1] etc... ] in this specific order
```

I've already tried to use a loop but the output is

```
P = [D[0][0],D[0][1],D[0][2],D[0][3]][D[1][0],D[1][1],D[1][2],D[1][3]]
```

Comment: Please include the exact code you've tried to use already so we can see where you're having trouble. It looks like you might be using two for loops but in the wrong order?

Comment: I understand what you mean about the expected input and output, but I still wouldn't say this is a complete or verifiable example. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Check with this

```
P = sum(D,[])
P[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 1], [0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is your desired output:

```
import itertools

D = [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]]

P = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*D)))
print(P)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you describe your problem, you can achieve your desired output using `sum` along with `zip` and `map`, which is rather complicated and not efficient, but it will do your job:

```
D = [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 1]], [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0]]]

P = sum(list(map(list,zip(*D))),[])

print(P)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 0]]
```

You need to provide some additional details to your question, such as the desired output of the above.